# mui autocomplete original filter option

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Is there a way to customize the filtering process for completions using the AutoComplete feature in MUI?
For example, if there is a list of alphabetical numbers "one, two , three" and the user enters "1", I would like to implement something where only one is displayed in the completion function.

i wrote below. but not working.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const options = [
  { value: "one", label: "One" },
  { value: "two", label: "Two" },
  { value: "three", label: "Three" }
];

function MyAutocomplete() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const handleInputChange = (event, newValue) => {
    const inputValue = newValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;
    const filteredOptions = options.filter(
      (option) =>
        option.label.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue ||
        option.label.slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue ||
        option.value.slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
    );
    if (inputValue === "1") {
      setValue([options[0]]);
    } else {
      setValue(filteredOptions);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      filterOptions={(options, state) => options}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Number"
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            onChange: handleInputChange
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```